# How to keep the application running without using partial wakelock

Tags: android, android-service

I have a single started service in my application which keeps my application alive.
I am downloading the data in a thread in my application(may take from 1 minute from 30 minute).
I want my application not to go in sleep state. I dont want to use the PARTIAL_WAKELOCK mechanism to keep the battery life long.

```
Here, The intention of having some PARTIAL_WAKELOCK like functionality not because of the service, 
I want it just for few threads(tasks).
```

Can AlarmManager help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want my application not to go in sleep state.

Then use a `WakeLock`.

> I dont want to use the PARTIAL_WAKELOCK mechanism to keep the battery life long.

You do not have a choice.

> Here, The intention of having some PARTIAL_WAKELOCK like functionality not because of the service, I want it just for few threads(tasks).

A `WakeLock` does not affect a service. It does not affect a "few threads". It affects **the device's CPU**. The CPU is what goes to sleep, not your service, and not your threads. If you do not want the CPU to go to sleep, you must use a `WakeLock`.

Comment: If the CPU will not go sleep. That means, other applications those are in background will be benefited from going to sleep state When my app would be in wake lock state?

Comment: @user2155922: If the CPU is running, all processes eligible to run will run, which includes other applications.